# jQuery - Change image src on hover

Tags: jquery

Basically I want to change the image src to add `-active.png` on hover.

So fb.png would become fb-active.png on hover, and fb.png when it's not hovering.

I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong so I'll post my code so far:-

**HTML**

```
        <div id="main-contact" class="right">

            <div id="main-social">

                <a href="#!"><img class="img-social" alt="Company - Facebook" class="left" src="images/fb.png" /></a>

                <a href="#!"><img class="img-social" alt="Company - Twitter" class="left" src="images/twitter.png" /></a>

                <a href="#!"><img class="img-social" alt="Company - LinkedIn" class="left" src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>

                <a href="#!"><img class="img-social" alt="Company - Word Press" class="left" src="images/wordpress.png" /></a>               

            </div>

        </div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){
    var regexactive = /-active\..*$/;

    var ct = $('#main-social');
    var imgs = $('.img-social img', ct);

    function activateImage(imgs){
        imgs.each(function(){
            var img = $(this);
            var src = img.attr('src');
            if( !regexactive.test(src) ){
                img.attr('src', src.replace('.png', '-active.png'))
            }
        });
    }

    ct.on('hover', '.img-social', function(){


        var img = $('.img-social img');
        activateImage(img);
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Why not just give CSS image sprites a try?

Comment: why you have added two classes in your html code? use only one css, if you want to add two or more you can add as class="img-social left"

Comment: ^ thanks, was a mistake (didn't realise some how)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done without javascript, with only css.
Like this:

Give different classes for icons like `fb` for facebook,`tw` or twitter and so on.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-social">    
    <a href="#!"><span class="img-social fb left" title="Company - Facebook"></span></a>
    <a href="#!"><span class="img-social tw left" title="Company - Twitter"></span></a>
    <a href="#!"><span class="img-social ln left" title="Company - LinkedIn"></span></a> 
    <a href="#!"><span class="img-social wp left" title="Company - Word Press"></span></a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-social{display:inline-block;height:20px;width:20px;}
.fb{background:url("images/fb.png");}
.fb:hover{background:url("images/fb-active.png");}
.tw{background:url("images/twitter.png");}
.tw:hover{background:url("images/twitter-active.png");}
.ln{background:url("images/linkedin.png");}
.ln:hover{background:url("images/linkedin-active.png");}
.wp{background:url("images/wordpress.png");}
.wp:hover{background:url("images/wordpress-active.png");}
```

You can use sprite for efficiency.

Comment: I was going to use the -active for many other hover states, would it still be best practice to do it this way still?

Comment: don't worry, sometimes I forget the simple things and end up using jQuery too much and when not needed

Comment: -1 as question title and example specifies jQuery to be used.

Answer (score 21):

You could do this just in CSS if you don't need to be compliant with older browsers.

To do it in jquery, you can try something like this:

```
$(".img-social").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace(".png", "-active.png");
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("-active.png", ".png");
    });
});
```

Comment: Which older browsers can't do `:hover`?

Comment: IE up to 6 only supports hover on elements with a 'href' attribute: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Comment: Noted. But the OP *is* using `a href` and besides IE6 is 13 years old!

Comment: In the question, the hover style must not be applied to the <a> tag, but to the <img> one, so it is not using an element with 'href' attribute.

Concerning the age of IE6, I know, but still I see some clients askings for compatibility with it :/

Comment: Fair point. I didn't interpret the OP's question quite that way - I assumed the need to change the img src on-hover was on hover of the link that wrapped it but you are quite right that the OP's request was for on hover of the img (although the OP did not state that the behaviour 'must not' be applied to the `a` as you suggest). Ultimately, I stand corrected and thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 6):

You can use mouseenter, mouseleave functions.

```
<a href="#" class="hover-change-img"><img src="sample1.png" class="img-responsive"></a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("document").ready(function(){ 
        $(".hover-change-img img").mouseenter(function(){       
            $(this).attr('src','sample2.png');      
        });     
        $(".hover-change-img img").mouseleave(function(){       
            $(this).attr('src','sample1.png');      
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this script.. base on the script above... it just switch between the active and original image.

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 
        $(".my_image").mouseenter(function(){       
            $(this).attr('src',function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace(".png", "-active.png");
    });      
        });     
        $(".my_image").mouseleave(function(){       
            $(this).attr('src',function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("-active.png",".png");});      
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Add some description it would be more helpful than just piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra attribute to your image, like "alt_img" and then just wait for the hover event and switch the attributes. Its a very simple approach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var src = "";
    var alt = "";
    $("document").ready(function(){ 
        $(".img-fluid").mouseenter(function(){       
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var alt = $(this).attr('alt_img');
            $(this).attr('src',alt);      
            $(this).attr('alt_img',src);      
        });     

        $(".img-fluid").mouseleave(function(){       
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var alt = $(this).attr('alt_img');
            $(this).attr('src',alt);      
            $(this).attr('alt_img',src);     
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's load of ways of doing this. One of the simplest is to have the two states in the same image and then just changing the background position on hover. This way there's no extra wait for the hover image to load as its already there.

```
<div id="main-social">
    <a href="#!" alt="Company - Facebook" class="left fb">facebook</a>
    <a href="#!" alt="Company - Twitter" class="left tw">twitter</a>
    <a href="#!" alt="Company - LinkedIn" class="left li">linkedin</a>
    <a href="#!" alt="Company - Word Press" class="left wp">Wordpress</a>               
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-social a {
    width:  50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent:-1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-position: left top;
}
#main-social a.fb {
    background-image: url('fb.png');
}
#main-social a.tw {
    background-image: url('tw.png');
}
#main-social a.li {
    background-image: url('li.png');
}
#main-social a.wp {
    background-image: url('wp.png');
}
#main-social a:hover, #main-social a.active {
    background-position: left bottom!important;
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c42b4/2/)