# How to change an image on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to do something like this.

```
<a href="#" class="change-hover" >
<img src="img/image-1.jpg"  alt=""/>
<img src="img/image-2.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="change-hover" >
<img src="img/image-3.jpg"  alt=""/>
<img src="img/image-4.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

By default 'image-1.jpg' & img/image-3.jpg etc.. should show , On mouse over 'a' tag, hide first image and show 'image-2.jpg' & 'image-4.jpg' etc..

For reference please have a look at this Product display. 
http://www.thecorner.com/searchResult.asp?dept=tcshoesw&brand=25&gender=D&norewrite=1

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Change image src on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752986/jquery-change-image-src-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to show the second image on hover and hide it on `mouseout`, showing the first, then you can use `hover` method like in below example.

Note, that the second image is initially hidden with CSS.

```js
$('.change-hover').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').hide().last().fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').hide().first().fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.change-hover img {
    display: none;
}
.change-hover img:first-of-type {
    display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="change-hover">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/1"  alt=""/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2" alt=""/>
</a>

<a href="#" class="change-hover">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/3"  alt=""/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/4" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks dude.. How can I apply a transition effect to  .show() event?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need jQuery to do this as you can do it easily using vanilla JS and even CSS.

You could save page load time by doing this (in vanilla JS):

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/image-1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'img/image-2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src = 'img/image-1.jpg'">
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/image-3.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'img/image-4.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src = 'img/image-3.jpg'">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS:

```
.change-hover {
    float: left;
}

.change-hover img + img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.change-hover img:hover + img, .change-hover img + img:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20Lhv9n9/).