# Changing the url of image src

Tags: javascript, imagesource

I'm trying to change to source of the images shown in a page.

I've got this code:

```js
function replaceSRC(){
    var allImg=document.getElementsByTagName('img'), i=0, img;
    while(img=allImg[i++]){
        img.src=img.src.replace(\'//dyncdn.me/static/over/, "\'//dyncdn.me/static/poster/3/");
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do next, im not really a script person i just wanted to make a site that uses to many small preview images to be seen bigger thats all.

the original source is:
`dyncdn.me/static/over/random numbers.jpg`
the source i want to use is:
`dyncdn.me/static/poster/3/same random numbers.jpg`

anyone can help out? thanks!

edit #1:
seems the site is using
onmouseover string to get the image source, while mouseout nothing shows. (only when my mouse is over the title the image is shown).

Comment: Your code is not valid Javascript syntax, the quoting is messed up. Why are you escaping the quotes? Aren't you seeing syntax errors reported in the console?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752986/jquery-change-image-src-on-hover

Comment: How can a question with CSS and jQuery only answers be duplicate of this

Answer (score 0):

Your string syntax is wrong. The replace line should be:

```
img.src=img.src.replace("//dyncdn.me/static/over/", "//dyncdn.me/static/poster/3/");
```

Comment: tried to change it but still the src of the image is the original.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(img.src)`?

Comment: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead

Comment: @DavidMarch I don't understand that comment, I don't use it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bookmark and change the URL to this

`javascript:(function(){var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) { var src=imgs[i].src; if (src.indexOf('static/over')!=-1) imgs[i].src=src.replace("/over/","/poster/3/")}})()`

Now click F12 to open the console, click the bookmark on the page you need to change and report any errors you see

Comment: didn't really understand what to do.
Created a bookmark of the page and changed the url no this one, clicked f12 and the console was open now what to do? :S